# Why do grape sodas taste radically different between US and Europe?

Tags: flavor, soda, grapes

I am talking about these super sugary artificially flavored sodas, or candies for that matter.

When I was a child and we went from France to the United States, I had absolutely NO idea that I was drinking a grape soda because the flavors are so different there was absolutely no relation to any flavor I ever had.

Later, as a traveling adult, I noticed that this hasn't changed. The 'super artificial made for kids grape flavor' of US products does not exist at all in the EU countries I know well (France, Spain, Malta, Germany), I don't recall ever tasting it in any of the other EU countries as well (I've been to most).

The opposite is more nuanced; I've tasted some US products (that were more 'adult' flavors) that were closer to the European ones.

The question is why is there such a massive difference in taste to the point the flavors can't be recognized as the same fruit (in theory)?
The opposite is almo

Comment: I don't know anything about those US sodas, but suspect this question is answered by https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81031/why-do-grape-flavored-foods-taste-different-than-actual-grapes

Comment: yes, I think the answer in that question fits exactly! thanks!

Comment: Also possibly that Europe has stricter standards for what you eat and drink. It was always explained to me that US companies do the cheapest simulation of flavors they can get away with and European companies are held to a higher standard. Don't know how true that is, but I would bet there is an element of truth to it.

Comment: @SteveChambers, I wouldn't be surprised. Having spent half of my life in each continent, it is very clear that the food is generally made with much cheaper ingredients in the US. That being said, the disclosure of ingredients in food is better in the US. I think the grape variety discussed in the other question is simply not common in Europe and is not the taste Europeans know.

Comment: The same is true for root beer; it is not a common flavor in most EU countries and most children only know it from cough syrups and a few other medications. So, imagine the first time they try root beer and it tastes like the syrup they always hated as a kid :)